# C++ Unable to write to file from buffer of variable length

Tags: c++, algorithm, io

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Open a .264 in c++.
2. Get the file size.
3. Read the file(buffer wise) in chunks of 128kb.
4. In the chunk of 128kb, search for a particular sequence of hex (header info).
5. Get the frame size(its at the 12-15th location from the start of header).
6. Copy contents equal to frame size into another dynamic buffer(of size    equal to frame size).
7. Write to an output file from the dynamic buffer from (6).

I'm facing two problems; An unsuccessful file write and the contents of my dynamic buffer don't change.Can someone explain what could be wrong?

[image] 
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

char const* inputFileName = "file15.264";
int file_open = open(inputFileName, O_RDWR);
//==================Global declaration of buffer===========================
static uint8_t buffer[131072];

//=========================================================================
//===========Snippet to calculate FileSize=================================
std::ifstream::pos_type filesize(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    return in.tellg(); 
}
//===========================================================================

//==============================MAIN FUNCTION================================
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    int input_size = filesize(inputFileName);
    float in_size_mb = input_size/(1024*1024);

    printf("Size of input File: %d bytes(%f Megabytes).\n\n",input_size,in_size_mb);

    int output = open("output_15.264", O_RDWR|O_CREAT);

    int bytes_read = 0;
    int foundAt = -1; //initializer for foundAt
    int index = 0;    
    unsigned int frame_size;
    static uint8_t * frame_buffer; 
    unsigned int array_size;
    while (bytes_read < input_size) 
    {   
        read(file_open,buffer,131072);
            while (index < 131072-8+1 )/* buffer has size 128Kb and hex seq to search is of size 8bytes */
            {
                if( 
                    (buffer[index + 0] == 0x00)&& 
                    (buffer[index + 1] == 0x00)&&
                    (buffer[index + 2] == 0x00)&&
                    (buffer[index + 3] == 0x00)&&
                    (buffer[index + 4] == 0x00)&&
                    (buffer[index + 5] == 0x00)&&
                    (buffer[index + 6] == 0x00)&&
                    (buffer[index + 7] == 0xab) )
                    {
                        foundAt = index;
                        printf("first byte in the sequence is located at index: %d\n",foundAt);
                        printf("Starting Address of Data: 0x%X\n",&buffer[index+32]);
                        //Bitwise Shift hex from buf[12] to buf[15] to get frame size  
                        frame_size = (  (buffer[index+12]<< 24)|
                                        (buffer[index+13]<< 16)|
                                        (buffer[index+14]<< 8 )|
                                         buffer[index+15] );
                        printf("Size of Following Frame: 0x%X\n",frame_size);
                        //write(output,(&buffer+32),frame_size);
                        array_size = frame_size;
                        frame_buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(array_size );//*sizeof(int));
                        printf("Size of Small buffer(frame_buffer):%zu Bytes & Contents' Size: %d\n",sizeof(frame_buffer),array_size);
                        memcpy(frame_buffer,buffer+(index+32),array_size);

                        printf("frame buffer[33]: %x [42]: %x [50]: %x\n\n\n",frame_buffer[1],frame_buffer      [2],frame_buffer[3]);
                        //sleep(3);
                        write(output,frame_buffer,frame_size);                           
                        index += frame_size;

                }
                else
                {
                    index++;
                }   


        }// END OF INTERNAL WHILE LOOP THAT SEARCHES FOR HEADER START
    //write(output,buffer+32,frame_size);
    index = 0 ;

    bytes_read += 131072;
    }//END OF OUTER WHILE LOOP THAT SCANS THE WHOLE I/P FILE HAVING FD 'FILE_OPEN'
    float j = bytes_read/(1024*1024); //just to return in mb the no of bytes read.
    printf("Total Bytes Read: %d Bytes (%f MB)\n",bytes_read,j);
    if(bytes_read == input_size)
    {
        printf("Copying Successful! \n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Error: Copy not Successful!\n");
    }

    close(output);
    close(file_open);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `read`

Comment: It's quite odd to initialise the `file_open` handle as a global variable as you're relying on any dependent globals in the translation unit that defines `open` to have been initialised before yours. Recommend moving that to main() and check for failure to open.

Comment: `float j = bytes_read/(1024*1024);` does integer division then assigns the result to `float`, so you will always see `0 MB` until it's read a whole meg, then `1 MB` etc.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was quite silly (i'm a noob), I had to delete the previously created file and executable. Now it is showing complete file size of 42 Mb. However the other problem still exists i.e in the 128kb data i'm copying to a buffer, there may lie many frames (identified by frame header of 32bytes), and i'm trying to copy each frame to another dynamic buffer and then write to file from that dynamic buffer. Upon doing so (as is shown in above pics), the data being copied to the dynamic buffer is same over and over again.

Comment: Why are you allocating `(array_size*sizeof(int))` bytes but only reading `array_size` bytes?  Also you never free this allocation .

Comment: They're same for that 128kb of buffer, but different otherwise. The file read is successful as it returns the number of bytes it read.

Comment: This line has the wrong format specifiers: `printf("Size of Small buffer(frame_buffer):%d Bytes & Contents' Size: %x\n",sizeof(frame_buffer),array_size)` . `sizeof` needs `%zu`, and `array_size` needs `%d`.  It seems from your code that `array_size` and `frame_size` should be `uint32_t`.  Also, printing the size of a pointer is redundant

Comment: @MattMcNabb I made the changes you suggested, but it made no difference. Also can't use uint32_t since the code eventually has to be executed on an MCU.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69386/discussion-between-shehryar-and-matt-mcnabb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
memcpy(frame_buffer,buffer+32,array_size);
```

should be

```
memcpy(frame_buffer,buffer+(index+32),array_size);
```

Or else you are just copying from the start of the buffer plus 32 bytes no matter where you find the header.

You can handle the case where the header extends beyond the current block of 128Kb like this: First double your buffer size:

```
static uint8_t buffer[262144];
```

then if there is overflow then read another block into the top of your array, and copy it down to the bottom half after you have read out the portion that straddles the two blocks:

```
int overflow = 0;
if((buffer+(index+32)+array_size) >= 131072)
{
    // read an extra block:
    read(file_open,buffer+131072,131072);
    overflow = 1;
}
memcpy(frame_buffer,buffer+(index+32),array_size);
if(overflow != 0)
{        
    memcpy(buffer,buffer+131072,131072);
    index -= 131072;
}
```

It's not very elegant but it should hopefully fix the problem. It assumes that array_size is never greater than 131072-32.

Comment: It gives me segmentation fault after writing 121kb to file.

Comment: The reason for that is probably that you are encountering a header that is near the end of your buffer, and extends into the next block of 131072 bytes

Comment: Yeah that might be it.So what should I do in that case?

Comment: your method works. Though there still is some frame loss but nothing compared to what I had before. Thanks Alot !